# JQuery validation not fired on form submit

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem getting a jquery validation to fire when a form is submitted. The form is rendered in a modal window and is called from two separate pages. One works just fine and validates before submit, however, the other just submits the form and triggers no validation errors.

It's a CodeIgniter system so each of the source pages call the modal as a view and load at runtime.

Each source page has the jquery script at the bottom of the page.

The jquery scripts are obviously in different files so have done 'diff checker' on them. They are exactly the same.

I have checked the jquery selector is calling the html form element's id attribute.
I have also checked that this is unique for the html page.

```
// modal is called from each source page as follows:

<?php $this->load->view('partials/modal-book-appointment', $data) ?>

// modal form is defined as follows:
<form action="<?= base_url(); ?>Appointment/savepatientform" method="post" da role="form" class="form-horizontal" 
    id="submitform-validation" enctype="multipart/form-data">

...
// modal submit buttons:
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
<a onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Book an Appointment</a>
<a onclick="$('#modal_book_appointment').modal('hide')" type="button" class="cancel pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>

// jquery validation code.
$(function () {
// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
        $("#submitform-validation").validate({

            // Specify the validation rules
            rules: {
                fname: "required",
                lname: "required",
                phone: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                agree: "required"
            },

            // Specify the validation error messages
            messages: {
                fname: "Please enter your first name",
                lname: "Please enter your last name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                phone: "Please enter your phone number",
                agree: "Please select the check box I acknowledge that this represents an accurate medical and dental history."
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

The form should validate but submits even if the 'agree' button is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form with JavaScript bypasses the triggers for the normal submit event handler.

Use a real submit button, not an anchor with some JavaScript attached.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have already tried that as I have read other posts suggesting same. I will try again, but that doesn't explain why the same code, with anchor, works when called from one page and then not when called from another. I guess it's just finicky?

Comment: I swapped out the anchor tags for this: <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Book an Appointment</button>
                                    <button onclick="$('#modal_book_appointment').modal('hide')" type="button" class="cancel pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div> still didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when ugrading my jquery 2.2.4 -> 3.4.1

I have a lib (i can't change) that catches the submit, does a bunch of stuff and then calls form.submit()
(but the HTMLFormElement form, not the jquery overloaded)

jquery 2.2.4 did trigger its listener, 3.4.1 doesn't anymore

i changed nothing else than the jquery lib

i attach my even like so : $('#myForm').submit(function(){...});

I tried with bind(..) and on(...) but as they are aliases ofc it did not change a thing.

I ended up doing the ugliest tweak ever but that works :

```
var form = document.getElementById('inscription');
        var oldSubmit = form.submit;
        form.submit = function() {
            form.submit = oldSubmit;
            $(form).trigger("submit");
￼   
        }
```

Ugly but until i understand how to attach it properly with the new jquery, this will be that